# Android - Disable all other items on dialog when clicked on another

Tags: android

How to disable all other items on dialog when clicked on another? Below is my code

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};    
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setTitle("Select Sources");
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null, new OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
        if(items[which] == "Red"){
            //Disabled Green and Blue items
        }
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Modify the following code according to your needs:**

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
    if(items[which] == "Red"){
        ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().setItemChecked(which,false);//this line will help you disabling the other options.      
    }
}
```

Comment: He didn't ask about unchecking, but how to disable it.
Otherwise it would make sense to use setSingleChoiceItems instead.

Comment: @mice: I have one item call "ALL", I want if that item was selected, all other items will be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You may do it so, that you don't use built-in Dialog's check-item list, but provide your own, where you can do anything on items.

You may use CursorAdapter (extend this class) and set it by setAdapter on a ListView in your layout inside dialog (use DialogBuilder.setView to set the list view).

In CursorAdapter implement mainly newView (where you create compound view made of item name and a checkbox encapsulated in LinearLayout, you may inflate this from resources.
And implement bindView to setup single item - it's name, checkbox state and enabled/disabled state.

In short: AlertDialog offers only simple multi-option list. If you need customizations, you must go longer way by using own list adapter.